# MS Teams: failed to add app to the MS Teams by user

Tags: .net, azure, bots, microsoft-teams

Our MS Teams app is published in MS Teams App center.
Customer added app to the global MS Teams policy and pinned it. All permissions are granted.

1. User opens Teams
2. User click on our app
3. User see the 'Add' button on our app
4. After clicking on 'Add' button user sees the 'Something went wrong' error message

The consolo logs contain the following errors:
0.2-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:114 2021-08-10T15:45:52.398Z add-app-dialog-v3-add-button: **ensuring app is installed for personal failed [object Object]**

Everything works for few users of organization. But most users see this error.
Any ideas why it is happening?

Comment: Can you share the manifest? Have you created a bot channel registration for it or doing with App studio?

Comment: We have the bot channel registration in azure. The manifest was generated via App Studio. Everything works great for hundreds of thousands of users and hundreds of customers (tenants).
The issue is just reproducing for 1 tenant that is GCC. We thought the GCC is the root cause, however for some users in their tenant everything is OK.

Comment: So is it not happening for all user in GCC? Do you have bot channel registration in GCC tenant?

Comment: For some users in GCC in this tenant everything works. What do you man - bot channel registration in GCC? In Azure our bot channel registration is not GCC. We supposed that it can be reason, however for some users it works.

Comment: Customer created the Microsoft ticket in their tenant. Looks like the root cause of the issue is that they also need to add 'Chat' to the global policy. Can it be the issue? If so, maybe it is somewhere documented? Looks like the issue is not reproduced for users with 'Chat' in global policy.

Comment: Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, it solved it

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any document telling you need to add 'Chat' to the global policy.

But I am sharing few documents link which you should have a look

1. [Install apps setup policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoftteams/teams-app-setup-policies?WT.mc_id=TeamsAdminCenterCSH#install-apps)
2. [Manage app permission policies in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoftteams/teams-app-permission-policies)
3. [Allow and block the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoftteams/manage-apps#allow-and-block-apps)

Comment: We followed all of these links, but only adding the Chat to the Global policy solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Customer created the Microsoft ticket in their tenant. Looks like the root cause of the issue is that they also need to add 'Chat' to the global policy.